# Why does assigning a member raise NullReferenceException?

Tags: c++, class, nullreferenceexception

I've been trying to get this code to work for quite a while now and unfortunately, I've always gotten `NullReferenceException`. I've found that this code works if one doesn't use pointers to the class but I don't see why pointers could cause this exception.  By the way, I'm not very experienced with c++ so it would be kind of you to explain this in a simple manner.  Thanks in advance.

```
class Box
{
    public: char* data;
};
int Main()
{
    Box* a;
    a->data = "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Box* a;` declares a *pointer* to a `Box` object. You don't ever *create* a `Box` object so `a` doesn't point to anything.

The behaviour writing `a->data` is therefore *undefined*.

Either drop the pointer so you get `Box a;`, or use `Box* a = new Box();`. In the latter case, don't forget to call `delete a;` at some point else you'll leak memory.

Finally, writing `a->data = "Hello World";` could be problematic: `a->data` will then be a pointer to a *read-only* string literal; the behaviour on attempting to modify the contents of that buffer is *undefined*.

It's far better to use a `std::string` as the type for `a`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my problem but could you perhaps also write how one should write `a->data` properly?

Comment: I would arrange things so the *constructor* for `Box` took a `const std::string&` to the data you want to set, and you assign the `a` member to that constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A *pointer* to a `Box` object is *not* a `Box` object. The pointer `Box* a` points to a non-existing object, that's why you get an error when you try to assign "Hello World" to a member.

You should create a `Box` object either by creating it "on the stack" with *automatic storage duration*:

```
Box a;
```

or by creating it "on the heap" with *dynamic storage duration*:

```
Box* a = new Box;
```

and delete it after use:

```
delete a;
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer just points to a (hopefully) allocated chunk of memory. In your example, the pointer is uninitialized, and so you're trying to set memory which you don't have access to.

You should ensure that it points to something valid, like this:

```
int Main()
{
    Box box; // stack allocation
    Box* a = &box; // you could also call new Box; here
    a->data = "Hello World";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `a` is undefined because you never set it to anything. Therefore, anything can happen. The most likely thing is that you access memory that is not yours, triggering a segmentation fault or a similar access exception. This is what happened.

Don't do this. Define your address in terms of the address of a variable of the same type that is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

`a` isn't initialized (or assigned), it's just a dangled pointer. Any dereference on it will be [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You could `Box* a = new Box`, or `Box b; Box* a = &b` to make the pointer valid. e.g.

```
Box* a = new Box;
a->data = "Hello World";
...
delete a;
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `new` here. Now OP will think that all pointers need to be newed.

Comment: @juanchopanza I just answered against OP's question. And yes, if you want to accessing members via pointer like this, it need to be newed.

Comment: No, `new` and dynamic allocation is a completely separate issue to using a pointer. No wonder people get so confused about this, with answers like this one. All that is required is that `a` point to a `Box` object. That's it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry can't get what you mean. "No reason to use `new`", means OP should just `Box a; a.data=...`, and I should point this, but not only telling him `a` should be `newed` here?

Comment: No, it means that in C++ (and C) pointers do not need to point to dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried to change the description to be more accurate.